# Sort field items

Tags: 7, nodes, entities

what is proper moment of drupal execution to sort fields in node display? One of content types has this list which points at other nodes, showing links with their titles. Problem is, they're not sorted alphabetically. I don't wanna use views. Should I do the sorting in node--content-type.tpl.php or rather some field hook? Examples appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function my_theme_preprocess_field(&$variables, $hook) {
 if($variables['element']['#field_name']=="field_project_release_packages"){
 usort($variables["items"], "_my_theme_sort_package_list");
 }
}

function _my_theme_sort_package_list($a, $b) {
    return $a["#title"] > $b["#title"]; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several options:
       -

- You can sort the array of the field.
  http://php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php
- You could use a jQuery plugin to do the sorting for you.
- You could write custom sorting code.

Comment: I know php sort but my question is about proper moment for sorting to reduce time and maximize efficiency. I just did it in node.tpl.php but items of field are in the same array as other attributes (pic: http://i.imgur.com/AQrWV.png ) so first I need to fetch them to my array (and pop), sort it, and then assign it back to $content. Maybe if I use sorting with callback I could do this without it..

Comment: jQuery is last resort as I want to make it browser/platform(ie. mobile) independent.

Comment: ..so as your idea of jquery matches my question, the other 2 clues are unfortunately too generic - where should I write my own code -- some hook? -- node.tpl.php? thank you.

Comment: The best way to to do this is in the hook_preprocess_node function. 
This hook should be implemented in the template.php file in the root of your theme folder.

Comment: Ok, that's better. But this means we sort them everytime we load page. Maybe there's a way of modifying SQL query that fetches records to sort them while doing SELECT?

Comment: unfortunately I can't change items in $variables during hook preprocess node, I get message of memory allocation error. I keep investigating..